# $\sigma$-Algebras $\mathcal{F}(X)$ independent of both $\mathcal{F}(Y)$, $\mathcal{F}(Z) \implies \mathcal{F}(X)$ independent of $\mathcal{F}(Y,Z)$

Tags: probability-theory

$\sigma$-Algebras $\mathcal{F}(X)$ independent of both $\mathcal{F}(Y)$, $\mathcal{F}(Z) \implies \mathcal{F}(X)$ independent of $\mathcal{F}(Y,Z)$

Am I right? It seems to follow more or less from definition, but I am suspicious if/why I dont need $\mathcal{F}(Y)$ independent of $\mathcal{F}(Z)$.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to guess what $\mathcal F(X)$ and "independent" might signify without looking at the tag?

Comment: Ah, I hate being trapped by intuition. My intuition get's screwed up, when thinking about independence of random variables. Intuitively it is just, $X$ has nothing to do with $Y$ nor with $Z$ so it can not have anything to do with $Y,Z$. Any intuitive counterexample on the basis of random variables?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the probability space

$$\Omega := \{1,\ldots,6\} \times \{1,\ldots,6\}, \qquad \mathbb{P}(\{i,j\}) = \frac{1}{36}$$

and define events $A,B,C$ by

$$\begin{align*}
A &:= \{1,3,5\} \times \{1,\ldots,6\}\\
B &:= \{1,\ldots,6\} \times \{1,3,5\}\\
C &:= \{(i,j) \in \Omega; i+j \mod 2 = 1\}. \end{align*}$$

Then it is not difficult to check that

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B) \quad \mathbb{P}(A \cap C) = \mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(C).$$

If we set $X := 1_A$, $Y := 1_B$ and $Z:=1_C$, then this shows that $\mathcal{F}(X)$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}(Y)$ and $\mathcal{F}(Z)$. On the other hand, it is not difficult to see that

$$0 = \mathbb{P}(A \cap (B \cap C)) \neq \mathbb{P}(A) \cdot \mathbb{P}(B) \cdot \mathbb{P}(C).$$

As $B \cap C \in \mathcal{F}(Y,Z)$, this means that $\mathcal{F}(X)$ and $\mathcal{F}(Y,Z)$ are *not* independent. Intuitively, this is due to the fact that if we know that $B$ and $C$ happen (i.e. we throw an odd number with the second dice and the sum of both dice is odd), then $A$ cannot occur (the throw of the dice has to be an even number).

Let me finally remark that even if the $\sigma$-algebras are pairwise independent, they are not necessarily independent. In fact, in the given example one can show that $\mathcal{F}(Y)$ and $\mathcal{F}(Z)$ are indepndent as well.